# Set text on top of cell while 1 cell on same row is setWrapText(true)

Tags: php, phpexcel, vertical-alignment

I'm working with PHPExcel to export data from website. So far, everything works fine with me. Here is my result [image: my result]

But as you see, the text in cell is aligned bottom. This is due to I setWrapText(true) on column G to display multiline in 1 cell.
How can I set the text in other cells on top?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you should really be working with PhpSpreadsheet rather than with the old, unsupported PhpExcel library:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setVerical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
```

as described in the doc